# Issue embedding SWF in IE8

Tags: html, flash, embed

I've got this piece of code trying to embed an .swf file to an HTML.

```
<object width="710" height="180" id="myMovie" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000">
                    <!--[if !IE]>-->
                    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/url_path/file.swf" width="710" height="180">
                    <!--<![endif]-->
                        <param name="Movie" value="/url_path/file.swf" />
                        <param name="Src" value="/url_path/file.swf"/>  
                        <param name="Url" value="/url_path/file.swf" />
                        <embed src="/url_path/file.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
                    <!--[if !IE]>-->
                    </object>
                    <!--<![endif]-->
                </object>
```

In Firefox, the .swf is loaded correctly, but in IE8 it just says "Movie not loaded".

I'm currently using Adobe Flash Player Version 10.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0" width="500" height="300">
     <param name="movie" value="mrsuniquez.swf" />
     <param name="quality" value="high" /> 
     <embed src="mrsuniquez.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="780" height="255"></embed>
</object>
```

Here you can try and use this.. Works in IE.